# Why does my html template in Mailchimp look different to what I receive on gmail desktop/mobile

Tags: html, css, email

As the title says, why does my html template look different on three different screen sizes? I understand that I haven't used media queries for responsive design, but to me, that doesn't explain why text is squished on gmails representation of the email, normal on my gmail app and 'gappy' on the mailchimp version. Can someone please help me with a solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no agreed on standards in email clients. They don't support the same feature base. Email clients like Gmail can vary wildly depending on what device you view them on. Some Gmail clients do not support `@media` queries. Even if developers take the time to optimize for each email client and version, things will vary between different versions. For instance, I get a different look between Gmail on Chrome than I get with Gmail on Explorer.